# What does “the Big Money crowd” mean?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I heard the following statement of Barron’s magazine piggybacked to today’s (April 28) AP radio news over AFN broadasting:

> “Two thirds of the money managers we surveyed think we are due for
>   collection of 10 per cent in the next twelve months before stocks
>   resume their rise. Favorable stocks, General Electric currently tops
>   the list. **The Big Money crowd** also likes bank shares such as Bank of
>   America and Citi Group.”

As I’m unfamiliar with the word, “Big Money crowd,” I looked for the usage of this word and found a pretty old example:

With bond yields edging up, about a third of **the Big Money crowd** thinks utility shares will be the worst performers in the next 12 months.” - online.barrons.com 2013/10/21

What does Big Money crowd mean, particularly ‘crowd’ here mean? Is Big Money a proper noun as B and M are shown in uppercase in the above Barron's example? Is "crowd" a mass noun that takes verb in singlar form like "likes" and "thinks"?

Comment: 'Big Money crowd' _is_ a proper noun, a fairly novel compound  (or at least an accepted collocation). It is still partially decomposable in that 'crowd' is seen to be a _collective noun_. In the UK (if 'Big Money crowd' were commonly used), notional agreement would often be used in this case ('the Big Money crowd think'), the members of the group rather than the nebulous super-organism being referenced.

Comment: In this context, _crowd_ is used much like the word _world_ is sometimes used. If I say, _The racing world was shocked when..._, I'm referring to those who have a vested interest in racing: owners, managers, executives, racers, and fans. I can also say, _The racing crowd was shocked when..._. In that sentence, the word _crowd_ could be referring to a crowd of spectators a particular race, or the word _crowd_ could also refer to _the racing world_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It refers to **Institutional  Investors,** that is 'Financial Institutions' that manage money on account of private people  or  private and public companies.

*Big Money* refers to the fact that they collect and manage  huge amounts of money (namely billions of dollars)

*Crowd* refers to the fact that there are quite a lot of these financial institutions in the business of money/asset management.

Comment: I hadn't thought much about the "quite a lot" part. I suppose if the number was smaller, the author might have used "club" instead of "crowd", which often implies some measure of exclusivity, and therefore smaller numbers. (That said, there's no fixed point on the number line where a _club_ turns into a _crowd_.)

Comment: I see your point, but I think that here crowd refers to the 'densely  populated' world of the financial institutions. Just my view.

Comment: In the world of financial institutions, how many of them fall into the Big Money crowd? Quite a few local banks probably wouldn't, which is why I'd consider that world _sparsely_ populated. Anyhow, [here's an interesting list](http://onlinebankingreport.com/resources/100.html); are all those institutions in the "Big Money crowd"? Or just the ones that are household names? The beautiful thing about English is that it's not precisely defined – if it were, there would be very little to talk about on ELU :^)

Answer (score 0):

Is "crowd" a mass noun that takes verb in singlar form like "likes" and "thinks"?

This can depend whether you are in the USA or the UK.  The USA considers Congress to be a single thing:  Congress thinks that ....   The UK considers Parliament to be the members that constitute it:  Parliament think that ....